# Multiple groupBy and sumBy in array of objects using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, nivo-react

I have the following data:

```
const rawData=[
  {
    Order_Date: "2020-08-11",
    Region: "South",
    Product_Name: "Bookcase",
    Sales: 261.96
  },
  {
    Order_Date: "2020-08-13",
    Region: "South",
    Product_Name: "Stacking Chairs",
    Sales: 731.94
  },
  {
    Order_Date: "2020-10-06",
    Region: "South",
    Product_Name: "Stacking Chairs",
    Sales: 700.45
  },
  {
    Order_Date: "2020-12-06",
    Region: "East",
    Product_Name: "Self-Adhesive Address Labels for Typewriters by Universal",
    Sales: 14.62
  },
  {
    Order_Date: "2019-11-15",
    Region: "East",
    Product_Name: "Table",
    Sales: 957
  },
  {
    Order_Date: "2019-11-10",
    Region: "East",
    Product_Name: "Eldon Fold",
    Sales: 22
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
      Region: "South",
      data: [
        {
           Order_Date: "2020-08",
           Sales: 993.90
        },
        {
          Order_Date: "2020-10",
          Sales: 700.45
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      Region: "East",
      data: [
        {
           Order_Date: "2019-11",
           Sales: 989
        },
        {
          Order_Date: "2020-12",
          Sales: 14.62
        },
      ]
    }
]
```

I want to first group by region and for each region I want to group by year and month ('YYYY-MM') of Order_Date  and sum by sales for each Order_Date('YYYY-MM') group.

I tried the following code but unable to get as expected output. I'm not understanding how to do this with multiple group by.

```
const groupByRegion = _(rawData).groupBy('Region').value();

const groupByRegionDate = _.forEach(groupByRegion, (value, key) => {
        groupByRegion[key] = _.groupBy(groupByRegion[key], (item) =>
            moment(item.Order_Date).startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM')
        );
    });
```

Comment: `rawData` cannot be "JSON", as JSON is a text format. Therefore, this question is about arrays and objects, not JSON, so let's leave it out, shall we?

Comment: I'd just use `item.Order_Date.slice(0, -3)` rather than parsing a date with moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let data = [{ "Order_Date": "2020-08-11", "Region": "South", "Product_Name": "Bookcase", "Sales": 261.96 }, { "Order_Date": "2020-08-11", "Region": "South", "Product_Name": "Stacking Chairs", "Sales": 731.94 }, { "Order_Date": "2020-10-06", "Region": "South", "Product_Name": "Stacking Chairs", "Sales": 700.45 }, { "Order_Date": "2020-12-06", "Region": "East", "Product_Name": "Typewriters by Universal", "Sales": 14.62 }, { "Order_Date": "2019-11-10", "Region": "East", "Product_Name": "Table", "Sales": 957 }, { "Order_Date": "2019-11-10", "Region": "East", "Product_Name": "Eldon Fold", "Sales": 22 }]
let results = []

for (let item of data) {
    let { Region, Order_Date, Sales } = item;
    let group = results.find(v => v.Region == Region);
    if (!group) results.push(group = { Region, data: [] });

    let groupItem = group.data.find(v => v.Order_Date == Order_Date);

    if (!groupItem)
        group.data.push({ Order_Date, Sales })
    else
        groupItem.Sales += Sales;
}

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Very close to the expected output. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Of course this is not 100% as you expected, Because I intentionally not  answered 100%, And left some todo for your (as practice)...